# JavaFx - transition for elements between a group

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm working on a JavaFx application. I have an group where I have two rectangles. If I make a transition for one rectangle, for example I want to move the first rectangle (x coordinate) to the second rectangle, the group will auto resize and when the transition ends the both rectangles will be in center. Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove both rectangles from any 'self-organizing' components such as vertical or horizontal boxes, flowPanes, gridPanes, put them in a regular Pane or AnchorPane if you still want to group them. Either that or you can try playing with the max and min width/height, maybe set resizeable to false. But those are guesses, hope it helps.

Comment: This works only in one sense. If I tel the left rectangle to go to the right rectangle, it works. If I tell the right rectangle to go to the left rectangle, it doesn't works. The right rectangle begins from the rigth(the initial position + the difference between left rectangle's X and it's X) and goes to the initial positon.